# Updating MongoDB nested array using same path as the search query

Tags: javascript, mongodb, robo3t, mongodb-update

I have the following problem, I want to update a document with a path id.metadata.panels.items where panels is an array and items is an array. My search query looks at the items and displays only those that match the criteria of metadata.panels.items.member.type: 'owner' - then I want to update the 'owner to 'account'.

When I am trying to update having the search path same as update path I get an error message saying: cannot use the part metadata.panels.items.member.type to traverse the element.

The documents have their own

How can I resolve this problem?

I have already tried to go through the collection using nested forEach statements to iterate through each of the arrays but I am not sure what to do next.

```
var records = db.getCollection('sample').find({"metadata.panels.items.member.type":"
[owner]"})
records.forEach(function(id) {
  var newFields = [];

  metadata.panels.forEach(function(panel, panelIndex){
    panels.items.forEach(function (item, itemIndex) {

      })
  })
})
```

Sample document structure:

```
{
    "panels": [{
    "name": "categories",
    "items": [{
      "member": {
        "type": "[Owner]",
        "subtype": "[Contractor]"
      },
      "format": {
        "members": {}
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "localisation",
    "items": [{
      "member": {
        "city": "NY",
        "state":"NY"
      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "panels": [{
    "name": "categories",
    "items": [{
      "member": {
        "type": "[Account]",
        "subtype": "[Contractor]"
      },
      "format": {
        "members": {}
      }
    }]
  },
  {
    "name": "localisation",
    "items": [{
      "member": {
        "city": "NY",
          "state":"NY"

      }
    }]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

```
var newFields = [];

var records = db.getCollection('sample').find({"metadata.panels.items.member.type":"
[owner]"})
records.forEach(function(id) {

metadata.panels.forEach(function(panel, panelIndex){
panels.items.forEach(function (item, itemIndex) {
    // I have generated update statements as strings
    // first list is always position 0 and this goes to the statement 
    // second list get's populated from itemIndex
    // added them to the newFields list
  })
}) 
})
 newFields.forEach(function(i){
  eval(i)
})
```